# Shiro grails pluggin 1.2.1 for LDAP authentication with grails 2.4.2

Tags: grails, ldap, shiro

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and have installed shiro grails plugin 1.2.1. I want to enable LDAP authentication and it is giving error being fail to get initial context from com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory (factory.getInitialContext(env)) throwing a NamingException,

Could not connect to ldap://:389: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0]

What could be the cause for this ?

Comment: This problem is solved by giving pain text as the Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS and appending domain to the Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL.